# PL/SQL All Possible Combinations Function

Tags: oracle, plsql

Working with PL/SQL in order to compute the number of combinations of k items chosen from a group of n values. I've recently created one to work with strings using recursion and it seems to work just fine, but now I want to use it for a group of entered n values instead of string values and can't seem to figure out how to tweak it correctly to work with values instead of strings. Here is my string recursion code.

```
create or replace 
  function print_anagrams
  (pre in varchar2, str in varchar2)
   RETURN varchar2
  As
    prefix varchar2(30);
    stringg varchar2(30);
    strlen number;
  begin
    strlen := length(str);
    if NVL(strlen, 0) = 0 then
     dbms_output.put_line(pre);
    else
      for i in 1..strlen loop
        prefix := pre || SUBSTR(str,i,1);
        stringg := SUBSTR(str,1,i - 1) || SUBSTR(str,i+1,strlen);
        print_anagrams(prefix,stringg);
      end loop;
    end if;
  end;
/
```

Comment: What are 'n values' - is *n* just an unknown number, or do you mean a list of numbers? Do you have to be passed a 'pre'-delmited string, or can you be passed a collection instead? And does it have to be PL/SQL? Showing sample input and expected output is always useful.

Comment: 'n values' will be the values inputted by the user, so yes a list of numbers. I'd like to perform as being passed a collection of values and as I'm trying to learn PL/SQL it needs to be in PL/SQL. So if one enters 1,2,3 it would print 123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321. Should've clarified, my appologies.

Comment: Is that different from handling strings really, if your input is still a delimited string like `'1,2,3'`? They happen to be digits instead of characters but does the procedure care? I meant 'collection' in [the PL/SQL sense](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm), not sure if you mean that or still a single string value. How will this be called - how is the initial list of values supplied?

Comment: I suppose it wouldn't make a difference what type it is if there entered in a string form, this is meant to be a function though instead of procedure where the values will be entered when the function is called and the combinations will be returned.

Comment: And as far as using a collection or single string value, I would rather it use from a collection than single string value.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want your argument that's passed in to be a "table of varchar2". See this article for more info: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jul/o42plsql-1653077.html.  Note that you could also use a "table of integer" if you wanted as well.